# primary key constraint error when doing an update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having a bit of challenge doing mass update in SQL server.  I have a table with composite primary key( studentid,login,pass). They have a common login and password as they are in a group. I m doing an  (again all same login and pass) update and setting their login and pass to new values where the field, class group =x.But I get a duplicate primary key violation error. Any idea why?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have a weird primary key, it's easy to see how it can be violated.  For example, say student 1 has two rows in the table:

```
studentid  login     pass                group
1          bobama    reallyborninkenia   politician
1          bobama2   raisetaxes          politician
```

And say you update the group  `politician`:

```
update  StudentTable
set     login = 'bobama'
,       pass = 'justpwndromney'
where   [group] = 'politician'
```

Then you'd get a primary key violation, since there would be two rows with the same `(studentid, login, pass)` combination.

If that is weird, that's because your primary key is weird.  I'd expect the primary key to be just `(studentid)`.

Comment: @Irfarino: If studentid were really unique, an update on columns other than studentid could not cause a primary key violation.  Try `select studentid from StudentTable group by studentid having count(*) > 1`.

Comment: True, there would be duplicate studentid's by itself but the combination of the three columns would be unique.

Comment: @Irfarino: Well, then SQL Server must be wrong to raise an exception ;-)

Comment: Lol I know it is me and not the db I m just trying to talk it out to see what I am missing. Will do some investigation and keep you posted cheers!

Answer (score 0):

well clearly there is a clash, you are are creating a studentid/login/password combination that exists in the table already. This query should show you where the existing rows that clash with your proposed changes are:

```
select t.* from [your-table] t
join (select * from [your-table] where [class-group] = x) proposed-change
on proposed-change.[studentid] = [t.studentid]
where t.login = 'proposed-login' and t.password = 'proposed-password'
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, there are currently lots of rows with same login/pass but unique studentid. All I m doing is updating the login/pass. But I will give it a try as you suggesed!